# What is the difference between mock.patch.object() and mock.patch()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to understand the difference between these two approaches of mocking a method. Could someone please help distinguish them?

For this example, I use the passlib library.

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch.object(CryptContext, 'verify', return_value=True) as foo1:
    mycc = CryptContext(schemes='bcrypt_sha256')
    mypass = mycc.encrypt('test')
    assert mycc.verify('tesssst', mypass)

with mock.patch('passlib.context.CryptContext.verify', return_value=True) as foo2:
    mycc = CryptContext(schemes='bcrypt_sha256')
    mypass = mycc.encrypt('test')
    assert mycc.verify('tesssst', mypass)
```

Comment: Is it just me or are these test cases not doing anything? They check that a mocked `verify`  method returns true as defined? I am genuinely confused unless this was just an example constructed to ask the original question.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You already discovered the difference; `mock.patch()` takes a string which will be resolved to an object *when applying the patch*, `mock.patch.object()` takes a direct reference.

This means that `mock.patch()` doesn't require that you import the object before patching, while `mock.patch.object()` does require that you import before patching.

The latter is then easier to use if you already have a reference to the object.

Comment: Another scenario where there's a difference: occasionally patching a pre-existing object might cause a problem, like when patching `datetime`. In that scenario, using `patch()` still works.

Comment: @mblakesley what kinds of problems? Perhaps you confused the module for the class; if you used `from datetime import datetime` then expected `mock.patch.object(datetime, "some_target")` to work then that will indeed cause issues. But that’s simply because the name `datetime` is not bound to the module. That doesn’t make `mock.patch('datetime.some_target')` special, just that that references the actual module.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Why wouldn't it be bound to the module? Let's say I do: `from datetime import datetime as dt`. Isn't `dt` the class? And isn't the class the base (first arg) for a patch? If none of this is correct, how would you propose patching `datetime.datetime.method` using `patch.object`?

Comment: @mblakesley: you can't mock any of the `datetime.datetime` methods directly. Not with `mock.patch()` and not with `mock.patch.object()`. You can only mock out `datetime.datetime` in its entirety.