# Python 3 Mocking Thread Target not working in Unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code and store in a file called `run_thread.py`

```
from mymodule import Builder 

def run_thread(): 
    threads = []
    for chunk in chunks:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=Builder.work, args=(a, b, c))
        threads.append(thread)

        try:
            thread.start()
        except:
            pass

    for thread in threads:
        try:
            thread.join()
        except:
            pass
```

When I try to mock/patch `Builder.work` in my unittest, the original Builder.work still run, which is NOT what I'm expecting.

```
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from mock import patch

@ddt
class TestRunThread(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('run_thread.Builder.work')
    def test_run_thread(self, mock_work):
        run_thread()
```

Comment: I tried this too, and still getting the same problem.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152170/what-is-the-difference-between-mock-patch-object-and-mock-patch?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: OK, try `@patch('mymodule.Builder.work')` instead of `@patch('run_thread.Builder.work')`

Comment: with a `mock_work.return_value = sth` or `mock_work.side_effect=[]`, the `@patch.object` is tested working

Answer (score 0):

When `patch` a class function, property, class attribute, this is used according to document

```
@patch.object(Builder, 'work')
def test_run_thread(self, mock_work):
    # this is tested to work with static method
    mock_work.return_value = ['a', 'bbbb']
```

class property and class attribute(not instance member) can also use

```
@patch('mymodule.Builder.class_attribute_or_property')
def test_mock_cls_attribute_or_property(mock_attribute):
    # this patch method tested not working for static method
```

Comment: It did not work for me because Builder.work() is a static method. So still use @patch.object?

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me because Builder.work() is a static method.

Comment: I am having fun to read this https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html